# Unexpected display of Dataset object

Tags: dataset

I have a dataset on which I apply a GroupBy on the rows and columns. I expected the output to be a table with the first grouping on the vertical, and the second grouping on the horizontal. However, what I get is the first grouping on the vertical, and the second grouping also on the vertical, nested inside the first.

The following screenshot from the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) shows what I expected.

[image: This is what I expected]

The following screenshot from my notebook is what I got.
[image]

Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them difficult to read. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, people who wan to helo you will have do a lot of work to reproduce your problem so they can experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but I find it difficult to express the problem I have without providing a picture. After all, the problem has to do with how the output *looks*.

Comment: I believe this is related to the underlying Association structure of the data. If you have a look at the `Normal` of the `Dataset`, it might help give some understanding. The second example shows a dataset with at least one extra "level" to it, and so Dataset acts a little differently. But it could also just be the data structure itself - for instance, Hilversum only has one sub-table (Aug 2019) where the rest have more.

Comment: There's a line in the documentation for `Dataset` about this: "Data without a consistent structure will not usually format in the same way as structured data". I believe this is what you are seeing here.

Comment: @CarlLange The consistency of the structure seems necessary but not sufficient. The keys should also be strings. At least in my case when the structure was corrected but the keys were still DateObjects, the formatting was still not as expected.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the strings issue before, but since you mention it I feel as though I've had the same problem before. Perhaps it's got to do with some sort of equality testing or something.

Comment: @Ruben you are right that providing an image can better describe your problem, especially when it regards how things appear visually, but the issue arises that the code is then also in an image form, and future users or those that wish to help provide an answer cannot copy & paste your code in an image form.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. Apparently there are two things here that Wolfram doesn't like.

1. Every cell should have a value
2. Column names should be strings

I had to fix both for the expected result to appear. Fixing one issue, but not the other, was not enough.

If anyone has an easier method to make this work I will gladly hear it.